# Get line length using SQL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql

I have a line dataset that has road names and different surface types along different segments of the road. I want to calculate the total length of each surface type for each road.

I've been able to get the groups and counts as I need using virtual layers / SQL

```
Select Road, SURF_TYPE, count(SURF_TYPE), geometry from road_extract group by Road,SURF_TYPE
```

Get's me

[image]

Rather than geometry I want to get the total length of each surface type.

I've found one workaround where if I have a column with $length in the the source table I can include sum(length) in the SQL to get the total length for each surface type but is it possible without having this column?

**Also is it possible to get this table formatted with the just the lengths like...**

```
Road,    Sealed, Unsealed, Floodway, Total
Airport, 15    , 0       , 0       , 15
Balonne, 20    , 5       , 0       , 25
Burke,   40    , 20      , 2       , 62
```

I have tried the following with no luck

```
select
 Road, SURF_TYPE,
 sum(length)
from
 road_extract

 Group by
  Grouping sets (
   (Road, SURF_TYPE, sum(length)),
   (Road),
   (SURF_TYPE),
   ()
  );
```

Comment: `sum(st_length(geometry))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is not so good at pivoting row values into columns.  If you know the column names you want you can write a very specific SQL statement, like this one:

`SELECT Road, 
Sum(case when SURF_TYPE ='Sealed' Then st_length(geometry) Else 0 End) As Sealed,
Sum(case when SURF_TYPE ='Unsealed' Then st_length(geometry) Else 0 End) As Unsealed,
Sum(case when SURF_TYPE ='Floodway' Then st_length(geometry) Else 0 End) As Floodway,
Sum(st_length(geometry)) as Total,
Count(*) as SegmentCount
FROM
road_extract
GROUP BY Road`

Answer (score 3):

You can try PostGIS `st_length` function and then pass geometry to it I have added SQL
snippet below for your reference

```
select
Road, SURF_TYPE,
sum(st_length(geometry))
from
road_extract
Group by
Road,SURF_TYPE;
```

Comment: thanks but I get an error - Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS select Road, SURF_TYPE, sum(st_length(geometry)) from road_extract Group by Grouping sets ( (Road, SURF_TYPE, sum(length)), (Road), (SURF_TYPE));: 1 - near "sets": syntax error

Comment: ohh my bad, I have edited my answer hope it works now.